# problema ao usar expressão regular para validar e-mail

Tags: javascript, jquery

Oi, estou usando a seguinte expressão regular para validar um campo de e-mail:

```
  var filtro = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;
```

a função que faza validação fica assim:

```
if(email.val() === ""){
   $("#valida_email").show();//mostra o <p> com a mensagem de validação
   passou=false;//quando retornar verdadeiro dá o submito no form em outra função
 } else if(filtro.test(email) === false){
   $("#valida_email").html("Preencha com um E-mail válido");
   $("#valida_email").show();
   passou = false;
 } else if (filtro.test(email) ===true){
   $("#valida_email").hide(); 
 }
```

eu testei da seguinte forma "tiago@gmail.com", mas não funciona, ele me retorna que o e-mail é invalido, alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendo muito de jquery para apontar onde ocorre a falha em seu código e ele está incompleto, seu problema não é a expressão regular para o email que testou.

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<input type="text" id="email"/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{ $('#email').focusout(function()
 { $('#email').filter(function()
  { var emil=$('#email').val();
            var emailReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;
            if(!emailReg.test(emil))
            { alert('Correto');
            }else
            { alert('Incorreto');
            }
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

Então fiz esse exemplo para que você possa adaptá-lo.

Comment: Ok! Reverti, bom teres dito para eu poder corrigir :)